# Date Trouble in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have boiled down a date query to its fundamental pieces in an effort to make a query easier for me to understand.  My trouble is that I am trying to trigger an append event if and only if theier anniversary date is equal to today or in the past.  My query works except when I get to the criteria of <=Date().  Here is my SQL.

```
SELECT ActiveAssociates_3.UserID
  , ActiveAssociates_3.[WM DOH]
  , DateValue(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([WM DOH]),Day([WM DOH]))) AS Anniversary
FROM ActiveAssociates_3
GROUP BY ActiveAssociates_3.UserID
  , ActiveAssociates_3.[WM DOH]
HAVING (((DateValue(DateSerial(Year(Date())
  ,Month([WM DOH])
  ,Day([WM DOH]))))<=Date()));
```

The WM DOH field is a ShortDate field, The Anniversary piece is a DateSerial merger of the hire date and month, with current system clock year.  The anniversary populates properly except when I use the <=Date() criteria...  I am wanting to only show anniversary dates that are equal to or before today. Thoughts...

Comment: Same Data Type MisMatch Error with <=NOW()

Comment: Dont know much about access but I doubt that you can put 3 fields in the HAVING condition it should be HAVING column day<= NOW,How to translate that in Access I don't know.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9aeafa62-02e6-43c1-93d7-24c73fc6542f/type-mismatch-error-in-access-2010

Comment: Why are you doing group by? you do not have any aggrigate funcation in the select statement

Comment: Hiten004 is right, you don't need the GROUP BY, but your query still works for me in Access 2010, even with the GROUP BY.

Comment: Do any rows have Null in `[WM DOH]`? `SELECT Count(*) FROM ActiveAssociates_3 WHERE [WM DOH] Is Null;`

Comment: I ran a check and came back with 0 NULL fields for WM DOH

Comment: Something seems odd about this.  I've been experimenting with variations of your `DateSerial` to `Date` comparison.  The only way I could trigger *"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"* was with Null in `[WM DOH]`.  But since that's not the explanation, can you upload a copy of your db to a file sharing site?

Comment: HansUp, I think I found it.  A related database has a null field in the DOH field...  I will correct that and see what it gives.

Comment: HansUp... If you can post the piece about Null field data I will accept that as the answer! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experimenting with variations of your `DateSerial` to `Date` comparison. The only way I could trigger *"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"* was with Null in `[WM DOH]`.

Exclude any rows where `[WM DOH]` contains Null.

Comment: BTW you should not need to feed `DateSerial` to `DateValue` because `DateSerial` returns a Date/time value by itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you query execute successfully.**  I have convert the having cluse to the where claus ePlease @DesertSpider use following SQL query.

```
SELECT ActiveAssociates_3.UserID
  , ActiveAssociates_3.[WM DOH]
  , DateValue(DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month([WM DOH]),Day([WM DOH]))) AS Anniversary
FROM ActiveAssociates_3
WHERE (((DateValue(DateSerial(Year(Date())   ,Month([WM DOH])   ,Day([WM DOH]))))<=Date()));
ORDER BY ActiveAssociates_3.UserID   , ActiveAssociates_3.[WM DOH]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking to answer: **has the anniversary passed?** or **is the anniversary today?**, so you can do that without knowing or evaluating the year.

```
WHERE
(
   --does the anniversary occur in a previous month?
   Month([WM DOH]) < Month(Now())
)
OR
(
   --does the anniversary occur this month, on or before today's date?
   Month([WM DOH]) = Month(Now()) 
   AND Day([WM DOH]) <= Day(Now())
)
```

Comment: So this will be the trigger to append vacation time as the anniversary passes.  SO lets say teh anniversary is tomorrow.  I dont want to see that user.  When tomorrow comes the append will bring that users new vacation information across.

Comment: @DesertSpider -- understood -- I think the WHERE modification I posted will ensure that you only see anniversaries that are today or before.